# How to use Ionic Storage to store json object from api with ionic 3?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic-storage

I would like to know how to use Ionic Storage to store Json Object with Ionic 3. I am finding it difficult as there are no examples for the ionic 3 and i am stuck. Nothing on the net seems to be updated. A supporting example for Ionic Storage would be of great use. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can store `JSON` objects in [**Ionic storage**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/).

```
  let your_json_object = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };

  // set a key/value
  storage.set('my-json', your_json_object);

  // to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('my-json').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your json is', val);
  });
```

Comment: How to store JSON from api? example from here https://randomuser.me/api/

Comment: Just access your rest API using `HTTP` and then store the result as shown above. What is the issue here?

Comment: Ok i'll try. Sorry i'm new to ionic

Comment: OK, sure. If you have any issue please let us know.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But i'm still confused in some part. Can i store my json locally so i can open it when i go offline, by using ionic storage?

Comment: Yes, you can. But I highly recommend using `Ionic Caching Service` module if you need to work on the `offline` use case. Since it has a lot of features. https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-caching-service/