# How to pass more than 2 arguments in ionic storage set method

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-storage

In ionic storage, I want set storage to login details. I have to pass 3 arguments only in single storage.set method.

```
signIn() {
const { username, password } = this
        try {
      const form = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)

      //like this
        //this.storage.set('USER_INFO', username, password);
```

**Do I have any ways to do that.
Thank you for the help**

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ionic storage documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage):

> Storage is an easy way to store key/value pairs and JSON objects

. 
You could save a json object with multiple entries in your storage object and achieve your goal of saving multiple "things" in one call like this ([related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217912/2174832)): 

Please also consider that saving the username and password of a user in localstorage is considered bad practice and considered a security risk. You can read more about this [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/hybrid-app-developers-dont-store-your-users-passwords/). An alternative approach could be to use token-based authentification.

```
let your_json_object = { "USER_INFO_name": username, "USER_INFO_password":password };

  // set a key/value
  storage.set('my-json', your_json_object);

  // to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('my-json').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your json is', val);
  });
```